# Factoring the imaginary unit

Tags: complex, factorization

Suppose you have this:

```
Collect[2 u + I + 2 + I,I]
```

It gives the same.

Is it possible to factor `I` in elegant way (not manually) to get following:

```
I(-2 I (u+1) + 2 )
```

Doing in `Block` environment does not help either:

```
Block[I=i,Collect[2 u + I + 2 + I,I]]
```

because here `I` is still global, I guess.

Comment: What, exactly, you are trying to achieve? What output you are expecting to see?

Comment: *VERY* inelegant, but works:  `(I (j /. Solve[2 u + I + 2 + I == I j, j]))[[1]]`

Comment: perhaps a crime against codemanity: `factorI[expr_] := 
 I Inactive[Plus] @@ (ComplexExpand[ReIm[expr]] {-I, 1})`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your direct method isn't working because neither `Complex` nor `Collect` works the way you are expecting. So depending on what you mean by "elegant", the answer to your question may be no.

You can jury-rig `Collect` to work using

```
expr = 2 u + I + 2 + I;
Expand[expr/I] /. Complex[x_, y_] -> x + i y
I Collect[%, i, Simplify] /. i -> I

(* 2 - 2 i - 2 i u *)
(* I (2 - 2 I (1 + u)) *)
```

You can also get most of the way there using `HornerForm`:

```
Expand[i expr/I] /. Complex[x_, y_] -> x + i y
HornerForm[%] /. i -> I

(* (2 - 2 i) i - 2 i^2 u *)
(* I (2 + I (-2 - 2 u)) *)
```

A useful general technique is to transform your expression into one where your idea of the simplest form coincides with *Mathematica*'s, `Simplify`, and then transform back:

```
expr/I /. u -> x - 1
I Simplify[%] /. x -> u + 1

(* -I ((2 + 2 I) + 2 (-1 + x)) *)
(* I (2 - 2 I (1 + u)) *)
```

Also, I actually like chuy's "criminal" method from the comments. You can `Simplify` each term to get the form you were looking for:

```
factorI[expr_] := I Plus @@ Simplify[ComplexExpand[ReIm[expr]] {-I, 1}]
factorI[expr]

(* I (2 - 2 I (1 + u)) *)
```

(I removed the `Inactive`, assuming you don't care too much which term goes first).

Comment: "Jerry-rig" (To fix an object (usually mechanical) to a working condition in a haphazard way. Also known as doing a MacGyver on it. This can apply to any non working thing, to fix it in a nonconventional way. This term was created during WW2, in reference to the Germans who were referred to as "Jerries" as slang. Allies often came across hastily repaired objects left by the Germans hence the term Jerry-Rig came to be http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jerry-rig)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Actually, apparently "Jury-rig" is the original term, dating to 1788: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/132919. It was a sailing term, referring to a mast built for temporary use.

Comment: @SimonRochester Hmmm... interesting.  I'd never heard "jury-rig."  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I wasn't sure either...I had to look it up.